# Moderator deleted my question as spam, but it is the opposite of spam - I am calling out the company's claims

Tags: support, deleted-questions

A moderator said my question looked like spam and deleted it. I was asking about   LiteSpeed Web Server with LiteMage Cache. It is a genuine question. I specifically called the company's claims into question and asked if I should believe them. That is the opposite of spam. I'm not promoting the company, I am questioning the company's claim. Furthermore, I really do need to know the answer.

**How can I have my question undeleted? I am open to editing it** to make it even more clear that I am not promoting the company in any way.

In case it is required, here is the url to my deleted question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298027/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry about that. I went through a list of spam posts containing "lite"-something. I guess thid got in the middle and disn't pay much attentìon. Will un delete it.

Comment: Thank you. If you want me to reword it, I'm happy to do so.

Comment: I made some edits. I hope it is more clear now. Thanks again.